# How can I change login model in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I want to use different model 'MyUser' from plugin 'Myplug' for user login in Cakephp 2.4. I tried in MyplugAppController,

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array(
                'plugin' => 'Myplug',
                'userModel' => 'MyUser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),
                'authorize' => array('Controller'),
                'loginAction' => array(
                    'plugin' => 'Myplug',
                    'controller' => 'my_users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ),
               'loginRedirect' => array(
                   'plugin' => 'Myplug',
                   'controller' => 'my_users',
                   'action' => 'index'
                ),
                'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
            ),
            'Form'
        );
```

and

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'plugin' => 'Myplug',
                    'userModel' => 'MyUser',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'authorize' => array('Controller'),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'plugin' => 'Myplug',
                'controller' => 'my_users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'plugin' => 'Myplug',
                'controller' => 'my_users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',
        ),
    );
```

but neither of them are working. It uses default 'User' model.

Comment: put this code in appcontroller and then try

Answer (score 1):

```
 'userModel' => 'MyUser',
```

That's wrong if its a plugin.

CakePHP uses the this notation everywhere for plugins:

```
PluginName.ClassName
```

This has to be

```
'userModel' => 'YourPlugin.YourModel'
```